# It prints twice

Tags: c, function, printf

This is really strange I tried but couldn't find .When I called function of Goblin , it prints the printf statements twice like this

Green Goblin throws a ghost bomb!

Green Goblin sends out razor bats!

Please help me I don't know how can i fix this , i fixed spiderman but goblin still prints twice ;_;

[Prints twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PIba.jpg)

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<time.h>
    enum MoveS 
    {
        Move1=6,Move2=9,Move3=10
    };

    enum MoveG
    {
        Move4=5,Move5=7,Move6=13
    };

    int spiderManAttacks(); //prototype
    int greenGoblinAttacks(); //protoype
    void printEnergies(); //prototype

    int main()
    {
        int spiderManEnergy=100;
        int greenGoblinEnergy=100;
        int moveSpiderMan,moveGreenGoblin; 
        int rateS;

        srand(time(NULL));

        printf("Battle begins!!!");
        do{
            rateS=rand()%100+1;

            spiderManAttacks(rateS,greenGoblinEnergy);
            greenGoblinEnergy-=(spiderManAttacks(moveSpiderMan));
            printEnergies(greenGoblinEnergy,spiderManEnergy);   



            greenGoblinAttacks(spiderManEnergy);
            spiderManEnergy-=(greenGoblinAttacks(moveGreenGoblin));
            printEnergies(greenGoblinEnergy,spiderManEnergy);



        }while(0<spiderManEnergy && 0<greenGoblinEnergy);

        printf("\nBattle ends!!");

        if(greenGoblinEnergy<spiderManEnergy)
            printf("\nSpider-Man wins! Yeah Spidey rules!");

        else if(spiderManEnergy<greenGoblinEnergy)
            printf("\nGreen Goblin won! Yeah Jack-o'-lanterns! ");

        return 0;
    }

    int spiderManAttacks(int rateS,int greenGoblinEnergy)
    {   


        enum MoveS moveSpiderMan;
        if(1<=rateS && rateS<=45)
        {
            printf("\nSpider-Man uses spider-sense!");
            moveSpiderMan=Move1;

        }

        else if(46<=rateS && rateS<=85)
        {
            printf("\nSpider-man shoots spider web!");
            moveSpiderMan=Move2;

        }

        else if(86<=rateS && rateS<=100)
        {
            printf("\nSpider-Man uses super agility and speed!");
            moveSpiderMan=Move3;

        }

        return moveSpiderMan;   
    }

    int greenGoblinAttacks(int spiderManEnergy)
    {   
        int rateG;
        rateG=rand()%100+1;
        enum MoveG moveGreenGoblin;
        if(1<=rateG&&rateG<=45)
        {
            printf("\nGreen Goblin throws a jack-o-'lantern!");
            moveGreenGoblin=Move4;  

        }

        else if(46<=rateG&&rateG<=85)
        {
            printf("\nGreen Goblin sends out razor bats!");
            moveGreenGoblin=Move5;

        }

        else if(86<=rateG&&rateG<=100)
        {
            printf("\nGreen Goblin throws a ghost bomb!");
            moveGreenGoblin=Move6;


        }

        return moveGreenGoblin;


        void printEnergies(int greenGoblinEnergy,int spiderManEnergy)
        {
            printf("\nGoblin %d Spider-man %d",greenGoblinEnergy,spiderManEnergy);

        }
```

Please Help me

Comment: return moveGreenGoblin;   

} <----  I forgot  this

Comment: edit your question and add it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's Homework.